# 2 body simulation paraview

Tags: simulation, paraview

I have 2 body coordinates and velocity data at different time steps. I want to visualize it using paraview. Can I have some suggestion on which file format to be used and where I can get those file formats?
Simulation should include velocity vector plot as particle passes through different points in space.

Answer (score 1):

There are many strategies that could be adopted. In you case, I believe it means you have numerous time steps, but little data per time step since you only have a two body problem.

One simple way, which might be quite inefficient however, is to create legacyVTK files using the language of your choice.

This very simple, ASCII file format, is explained here :
http://www.vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf

In your case you would have a large number of legacyVTK files, one per time step, and paraview would read the totality of them as a time serie. The downside is that this requires numerous files which have little data in them.

The are also pythons and matlab tools to write data into VTK arrays, which can be binary and which are also highly more efficient. 
At the following link you will find a function example in Matlab to export to VTK a regular 3D array.
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47814-export-3d-data-to-paraview-in-vtk-legacy-file-format?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Hope that helps!